# Hide ^M in process output buffers?

Tags: process, character-encoding

I have stack traces that are coming either from a process or remote server that have ^M at the end of the lines. I can disable read only mode and remove trailing white space, but it would be nice if I could just hide the unwanted characters automatically. I tried playing with set-buffer-process-coding-system, but it says no process.

This question is not the same as the many others asking about ^M characters because I'm talking about a read only buffer. There is no file being visited, so I can't set the file encoding.

Comment: Is the "read only" part relevant?  I.e. if you made the buffer writeable, would you want the carriage returns to be made visible again?

Comment: No, I don't want to see them; they're distracting. I see your point. The read only part doesn't really matter. The buffers I'm looking at happen to be read only because they are the output of a process. But I would want the ^M gone even if the buffer weren't marked read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Display Tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Tables.html) to achieve what you’re after.  Arrange for the following code to be run in those buffers:

```lisp
(setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))
(aset buffer-display-table ?\^M [])
```

(Also posted [on comp.emacs](https://web.archive.org/web/20150323211214/http://www.archivum.info/comp.emacs/2007-06/00348/Re-Ignore-%5EM-in-mixed-(LF-and-CR+LF)-line-ended-textfiles.html) many moons ago.)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer mostly does what I want, but it needs a little more work. I want to limit this to buffers that aren't files because, as it happens, I have at least one script with a legitimate ^M character. Also sometimes a buffer opens in a window without actually switching to it, so I think I need two hooks here.

```
(defun tg/hide-carriage-return ()
    (when (and (not buffer-file-name) (not buffer-display-table))
      (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))
      (aset buffer-display-table ?\^M [])))
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'tg/hide-carriage-return)
(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'tg/hide-carriage-return)
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly correct, but it seems to get the job done.